# How to style results from SPARQL query in RAP RDF API (PHP)

Tags: php, sparql, rdf

I 've been trying to format the results that SPARQL produces in RAP API for PHP.
I also want to know how to keep every value return by the query. For instance if the query is SELECT ?a ?b ?c ?d .... I want to know how to set this variables ready for manipulation.

For instance, I have written this code

```
// Include RAP
define("RDFAPI_INCLUDE_DIR", "rdfapi-php/api/");
include(RDFAPI_INCLUDE_DIR . "RdfAPI.php");
// Filename of an RDF document
$base="rdf-files/myfile.n3";
// Create a new MemModel
$model = ModelFactory::getDefaultModel();
// Load and parse document
$model->load($base);
// Query the model and print the result
$querystring = 'SELECT ?a ?b ?c WHERE{ ?a ?b ?c . }';
echo $model->sparqlQuery($querystring, "HTML");
```

This code produces an html table with the results of the $querystring. How can I style this table?

Comment: I'm really confused by your posts...why can'T you show the current PHP code and the current SPARQL query? I mean, it should be clear that nobody can help without any details.

Answer (score 0):

You can style Outputs by using:

**RDF resource** methods like `getLabel`, `getNamespace`, `getLocalName`, ...) and Literal methods.

> Every RDF resource must have a URIref. URIrefs are treated as logical constants, i.e. as names which denote something (the things are called 'resources', but no assumptions are made about the nature of resources.) Many RDF resources are pieces of vocabulary. They typically have a namespace and a local name. In this case, a URI is composed as a concatenation of the namespace and the local name.

And **RDF literal**.

> The literal supports the xml:lang and rdf:datatype property. For XML datatypes see: http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/

You can find more information in the [RAP - Docs](http://wifo5-03.informatik.uni-mannheim.de/bizer/rdfapi/phpdoc/index.html)

Comment: you can style Outputs by yourself by using Resource methods (getLabel, getNamespace, getLocalName, ...) and Literal methods ... etc